# Flink on yarn, container's physical memory used Has been rising

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

When I search for the container.it shows like :

```
yarn      38530 116969  0 Jul17 ?        00:00:00 bash /mnt/dfs/2/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/sloth/appcache/application_1526888270443_0045/container_e12_1526888270443_0045_01_000039/default_container_executor.sh
yarn      38533  38530  0 Jul17 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash -c /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java -Xms1252m -Xmx1252m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1820m  -Dlog.file=/mnt/dfs/2/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1526888270443_0045/container_e12_1526888270443_0045_01_000039/taskmanager.log -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:./logback.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskManager --configDir . 1> /mnt/dfs/2/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1526888270443_0045/container_e12_1526888270443_0045_01_000039/taskmanager.out 2> /mnt/dfs/2/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1526888270443_0045/container_e12_1526888270443_0045_01_000039/taskmanager.err
yarn      38540  38533  0 Jul17 ?        00:09:47 /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java -Xms1252m -Xmx1252m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1820m -Dlog.file=/mnt/dfs/2/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1526888270443_0045/container_e12_1526888270443_0045_01_000039/taskmanager.log -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:./logback.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskManager --configDir .
```

and I sort out like :

```
 YarnTaskManager  pid = 38540   
 container        pid = 38533  
 ???              pid = 38530  
 nodemanager      pid = 116969
```

I dump the YarnTaskManager's dump file ,it size is 400M+.
But  the container use more memory ,I got it from the log :

```
 2018-07-18 10:16:27,875 INFO  monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl (ContainersMonitorImpl.java:run(464)) 
  - Memory usage of ProcessTree 38533 for container-id container_e12_1526888270443_0045_01_000039: 
 1.7 GB of 4 GB physical memory used; 4.1 GB of 8.4 GB virtual memory used
```

The container has used 1.7G memory,and I check recent logs,It rising slowly.
I don't know why the memory container used is always rising, After a few days it will rising to 4GB ,and will be killed,then restart.
How and I stop this happened?
Thanks for hellping me !

Comment: Is it the heap dump you are looking at @spoon?

Comment: I think the off heap memory takes up a lot  for rockdDB

Comment: RocksDB uses off heap memory. At the moment it is hard to set an upper limit for the memory RocksDB is using because it calls into native code. However, you have some control over its memory consumption by setting the `DBOptions` and `ColumnFamilyOptions` via the `OptionsFactory`.